# query works in oracle 10g but not in 11g

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have this query that works in oracle 10g:

```
sMemberId := bertlv.GET_OW_TAG_VALUE(F0, 'D5', '');
stnd.process_message( stnd.Information ,'sMemberId = ' ||sMemberId);
if sMemberId = '147' then
   sBankToName := 'BMI';
else

--everything works until this line below:

select trim(max(upper(name)))
into sBankToName
from BIN_TABLE
where amnd_state = 'A'
and member_id = sMemberId;

stnd.process_message( stnd.Information ,'sBankToName = ' ||sBankToName);
end if;


If sBankToName is null or sBankToName = '' then
RetCode := 201;
ErrMsg := 'CUST_ACQ_TO_ISS: Destination Bank Not Found (' || trim(sMemberId) || ')';
return;
end if;
```

All work until the line when I am selecting a name and input a value into variable sBankToName.  This variable is NULL so then it returned an error message that I setup.  However, it should not be NULL because the condition was correct.  Could anybody please give me some input about this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are saying that Oracle returns `NULL` for your `SELECT trim(max(upper(name))) ...` query but that you believe that Oracle is incorrect, I've got to side with Oracle.  Realistically, there is no row in `bin_table` with an `amnd_state` of "A" and a `member_id` of `sMemberId` that has a non-NULL `name` that your session can see.  You'd need to debug why that is-- perhaps the row doesn't exist, perhaps it was inserted in a different session and not committed, perhaps there is some other issue (if `member_id` is a string perhaps there are some additional whitespace characters)

Answer (score 0):

First check that is it really null or what value is coming by printing it just after the select query with dbms_output.put_line and after that stnd.process_message line, here is the example:

```
select trim(max(upper(name)))
into sBankToName
from BIN_TABLE
where amnd_state = 'A'
and member_id = sMemberId;

dbms_output.put_line(sBankToName);

stnd.process_message( stnd.Information ,'sBankToName = ' ||sBankToName);
end if;

dbms_output.put_line(sBankToName);
```

Then you would be able to debug easily.